# would it be use to or used to?

Tags: grammar

Jasmine use to take  piano lessons, but now she is learning to play the trombone.

Jasmine used to take  piano lessons, but now she is learning to play the trombone

Comment: As mentioned in the possible duplicate, the confusion arises because the 's' in 'used' is pronounced with an 'S' sound in this compound tense (for most English speakers), and with a 'Z' sound elsewhere:  I used to go (=yoost); I used two gophers = (=yoozd).  In my dialect (Canadian) the  'oo' in the second pronunciation is also longer.  The 's' in 'use' *when it is a noun* is always 'S'.

Answer (score 2):

> used to

You are describing a past state, hence use of the past tense, **used**. If "use to" is found, or heard, it is most likely because the *-d* got lost in the following *t-*.

Comment: *Use to* would not (or at least should not) be written. If it is, it is because of unfamiliarity between written and spoken usage. I agree with you, though, that it is very common in speech for the reason you stated.